# HTML5 Canvas (SIMPLE PAINT APPLICATION)

Tags: html, canvas

I'm working on a paint application and I'm trying to centre the canvas onto the middle of the screen . Any attempts I made the detection was off(still at the top left of the screen) but it was visually appearing in the centre of the screen. 
      Basically it wont draw onto the canvas when I moved it to the centre of the screen.
Any help would be much appreciated , Thanks....
I HAVE MY CODE BELOW ...

Comment: Your code is not below.

Comment: i cant post my code because my reputation is below 10. anywhere i can post it so u can see?

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be better than nothing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/53qtu/ ....heres my link to the code , thanks.

Comment: Please edit in your original post.

Comment: My jsfiddle link is above by the way thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your question how you're centring it, but you need to account for any offset of elements which contain your `canvas` when you attempt to map the mouse position to a position on the `canvas`. You can do this by including the `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop`  values (see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.offsetLeft)) of the containing element when you do your calculations.

The following will work if you're offsetting the position of the `div` which wraps the `canvas` (which I've given an id to make it easier to reference):

```
function move(e) {

    // Get the div containing the canvas. Would be more efficient to set this once on document load
    var container = document.getElementById('container');

    if((e.button == 0) && (mouseIsDown)) { 
        g.beginPath();
        document.onselectstart = function(){ return false; }
        //g.fillStyle = "red";
        // Account for the offset of the parent when drawing to the canvas
        g.arc((e.x - container.offsetLeft) - brush, (e.y - container.offsetTop) - brush, brush, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        g.fill();
        g.closePath();
    }
}
```

And a simplistic demo using your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xcpRu/1/).

Comment: Thanks, i changed the div to 525px; top: 250px; and it put it in the centre , would that be acceptable? As it works?

Comment: You probably don't want to absolutely position it if you want it centred regardless of the window size - I just did it that way because it was a quick way of producing the test. I'd probably suggest using something like margin: 0 auto. But either way the method should work.

Comment: Oh ok well thanks very much you saved me a lot of trouble i was stuck for a good while !Thanks again !